# ng grid shift select bug selects additional rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

Checkout my plunker: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/l4rTo4qkjDlTfi1aQ0IO?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
// some stupid error won't let me paste the whole code, please check plunker
```

To reproduce:

1. select the first row by left mouse click
2. use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>end</kbd> to scroll to the bottom rows
3. select the row that says 'Select me...' using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> click
4. expected: rows until the 'Select me...' get selected
5. observed: additional rows get selected

Note: When scrolling the additional rows get deselected again.

Comment: Ui-grid works with two index : One for the real list and one for the visually accessibles row. Looks like a odd behaviour with the scroll checking too much row visually and the rights row in the real list. Avec some scroll it update the visual checking. Did you try to check on the ui-grid github if the issue as been reported ?

Comment: Could not reproduce it on ui-grid

Comment: Oh sorry, i misread thought you were on ui-grid ... but you can give a try to ui-grid maybe ? Does the github of ng-grid say something about this issue ?

Comment: I have to support IE8 too, so can't go with ui-grid. There's no mention of this issue on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added something like this, and it worked:

```
beforeSelectionChange: function() {
    var grid = angular.element('.ngGrid');
    grid.data('alreadySelectedItems', grid.scope().selectedItems);
    return true;
},
afterSelectionChange: function (rowItem) {
    if (rowItem.selected === true) {
    } else if (rowItem.selected === false) {
    } else if (rowItem.length > 0) {
        var selectedIds = [],
            grid = angular.element('.ngGrid'),
            renderedRows = grid.scope().renderedRows,
            alreadySelectedItems = grid.data('alreadySelectedItems') || [];
        angular.forEach(rowItem, function (row) {
            if (row.selected === true) {
                selectedIds.push(row.entity.Id);
            }
        });
        angular.forEach(renderedRows, function (row) {
            if (selectedIds.indexOf(row.entity.Id) === -1 && alreadySelectedItems.indexOf(row.entity) === -1) {
                row.selected = false;
            }
        });
        grid.removeData('alreadySelectedItems');
    }
}
```